# Stop serve_forever when rospy.is_shutdown

Tags: python, shutdown, ros, simplehttpserver, rospy

I have the following Python program to start an HTTP server and a ROS node.

```
httpd = ThreadingHttpServer()

rospy.init_node('server')
rospy.on_shutdown(httpd.shutdown)

try:
    httpd.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

httpd.server_close()
```

I want the program to terminate

- when I call `httpd.shutdown()` (e.g. after receiving a `/kill` command),
- when ROS is shutting down (i.e. if `rospy.is_shutdown()`) and
- when I press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> (this is least important).

Somehow I'm struggling with recognizing the ROS shutdown, even though I tried `rospy.on_shutdown()` and alternatively an own `while` loop calling `httpd.handle_request()`.

With the current version, the node (started with `rosrun`) does not stop when shutting down `roscore`.

How can I combine these two modules reasonably?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can stop by registering the socket close function on the  (or your own function that calls it) as a rospy shutdown handler.

```
   def shutdown_hook():
       print "Trying to shut down server"
       httpd.shutdown()

   rospy.on_shutdown(shutdown_hook)
```

If `shutdown()` doesn't work, try `httpd.socket.close()`

Comment: Yeah, `httpd.socket.close()` seems to work in my case. Thanks! :)